# precedence of local providers

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I'm new to Angular and Dependency Injection, sorry if my questions sound dumb.
Let's s we have a component called comA, a directive called dirB and a pipe called P
and P is expecting a service(called S) in its contructor to use. And both comA and dirB have their own local provider for S.

My question is, let's say comA uses dirB and P as

```
//This is comA.component.html

<table dirB>
...
   <tr *ngFor= "let item of ...">
      <td>{{item.price | P }}</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Below is my understanding, please correct me if I'm wrong:

**when pipe P need to use S, dirB's provider will supply the service object not the comA's local provider**

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I'm not sure you could have a situation where two different dependencies for the same interface would be provided to two different components/directives within a component.

Comment: @theMayer  since a component can have multiple directives applied to, and directives can have their own local provider,so I guess it is nothing wrong to have mutiple providers in a component

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3325-understanding-pipe-instantiation-life-cycles-in-angular-4-2-3.htm), the pipe is instantiated once per component instance. So, assuming you have the dependency injection hierarchy configured properly, you should get the same dependency that would be passed to your component.

It should be easy enough to test this. Do you have code and/or a specific example of it not working the way you think it should?

Comment: The main pupose for this post is I want to have official docs to confirm my poin. I understand that the pipe is instantiated once per component instance, but which one instantiates the service,  dirB or comA?

Comment: The docs don’t cover every scenario. Set this up yourself and try it out. If I have time I’ll do my own testing as well.

Comment: thanks for the comment again. I am that kind of person who only see official docs to be confident to use sth. At least now I know my post does make sense, I thought I had a misunderstanding on local providers